# How can I extract matrix elements corresponding to column list

Tags: r, apply

This seems like it should be very simple to do with an apply function, but I find myself struggling with it.

I have a matrix (dataframe ok also) of data:

```
u <- matrix(sample(seq(4),20,T),5,4)
u
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    4    2
[2,]    4    3    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    1
[4,]    3    2    4    4
[5,]    4    1    3    4
```

Suppose I just wanted to use the elements (like indirect in excel) of
column j to  select a corresponding column value from each row.

e.g. given col(j) = 3

> row 1 would get element corresponding to row=1,col(j=3)=4 and return 2 (row(1):col(4))
>
> row 2 would get element
> corresponding to row=2,col(j=3)=2 and return 3 (row(2):col(2))
>
> ...
>
> row
> 5 would get element corresponding to row=5,col(j=3)=3 and return 3
> (row(5),col(3))
>
> I end up with a vector of those values v<-c(4,2,...3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use matrix indexing:

```
i <- seq_len(nrow(u))
j <- u[, 3]
u[cbind(i, j)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following also works:

```
sapply(1:nrow(u), function(i) u[i,u[i,3]])
```